# How to know every column name referencing a primary key?

Tags: oracle

I found a query which gets every tables referencing a table :

```
SELECT UC.TABLE_NAME , UCC.COLUMN_NAME
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS UC, USER_CONS_COLUMNS UCC
WHERE UC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = UCC.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND UC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' 
AND lower(UCC.TABLE_NAME) = 'master_table';
```

Now my problem is how to know the column name in every tables referencing the master table ?

Comment: Is your query already containing column name?

Comment: it is the master primary key column name !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT uc.constraint_name 
      ,ucc.table_name as master_table_name 
      ,ucc.column_name as master_table_col 
      ,ucc1.TABLE_NAME as slave_table_name 
      ,ucc1.COLUMN_NAME as slave_table_col 
FROM   user_constraints  uc 
      ,user_cons_columns ucc 
      ,user_cons_columns ucc1 
WHERE  uc.r_constraint_name = ucc.constraint_name 
       and uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name 
       AND uc.constraint_type = 'R' 
       and ucc.POSITION = ucc1.POSITION 
      AND lower(ucc.table_name) = 'master_table'
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

I found also this one :

```
SELECT detail.TABLE_NAME table_detail , r_cc.column_name fk_name

FROM user_constraints detail, user_cons_columns master , user_cons_columns r_cc

WHERE detail.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = master.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND detail.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'  

AND LOWER(master.TABLE_NAME) = 'master_table'

AND detail.constraint_name = r_cc.constraint_name
```

Comment: You will get redundant rows if your primary key is composit